# How to hide debugging output in Mathematica?

Tags: printing, debug, mathematica

I want hide all outputs created by Print command from user's function defined in `module .m`.

More precisely the problem is following:

I have a module that solves some specific task (It's not necessary to know the task for understanding the question). I use Print command inside the module to output process of evaluation. It's useful for debugging but not for using (all inner output must be hidden when user calls a function declared in the module).

So, in every stable version of the module I have to put comments (`* *`) and delete them for gebugging. I suppose that this way is uncivilized, and Mathematica should have a regular way to hide inner outputs.

For example, we have 3 files in the same directory. Can you suggest me a simple way how to hide all outputs by default and print all outputs in debugging mode?

`modul.m`:

```
f[x_]:=Module[{y}, y=Cos[x]*Sin[x];
Print["modul.m: y=",y];
Return[y]];
```

`debugging.nb`:

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
<< modul.m;
x=10;
f[x] (* print all inner output generated while f is evaluating*)
x=20;
f[x](* print all inner output generated while f is evaluating*)
```

`application.nb`:

```
<< modul.m
y=f[10]+f[20];
(* Hide all outputs of f during evaluation. Command ; doesn't work for this issue. *)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer to this is that a simple `Print[]` is not a good way to debug a large package.  It is not possible to turn it off (in a robust way) *only* for your package, but not in other places (it *can* be disabled globally, the simplest way being `Print; Unprotect[Print]; Print = Null &`, but this will severely annoy your users)

For much better ways to emit debug messages, and turn them off, see here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8698754/message-generation-in-mathematica

I'll summarize Brett Champion and my own answers from there, as personally (and subjectively) I consider those the best solutions, but please read the full thread there.

---

**Brett Champion's answer:**

Use a custom symbol for debug messages(just like your package functions, you may want to put it in a separate context to avoid collisions), like this:

```
...
debugPrint[expr]
...
```

Then define a `PrintDebug` function like this:

```
Attributes[PrintDebug]={HoldAll}

PrintDebug[expr_] := Block[{debugPrint = Print}, expr]
```

Any code wrapped in `PrintDebug` will print messages.  If there's no `PrintDebug` wrapper, message printing is disabled.

```
MyFunction[1,2,3] // PrintDebug
```

Alternately you may set a value to `debugPrint` globally to enable message printing for everything or just do `$Pre = PrintDebug`.

---

**My answer:**

We can use the built-in `Message` functionality for debugging too:

```
debugPrint::msg = "Debug message: `1`";    
debugPrint[msg_] := Message[debugPrint::msg, msg]
```

Use the function like this:

```
debugPrint["hello"]
```

Turn off or on messages like this:

```
Off[debugPrint::msg]

On[debugPrint::msg]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I chose first solution (by Brett Champion's) since it can work with multiple argument in debugPrint `debugPrint["modul.m: y=", y];debugPrint["modul.m: y=", y,"z=",z];`
But the idea of using Message looks great. I wish there was posibility to define debugPrint with apriory unknown number of arguments.

Comment: @Anonimous When using the `Message` version of `debugPrint`, you can either put everything in a list before you pass it to it, `debugPrint[{1,2,3}]`, or we could do something like `debugPrint[args__] := 
 Message[debugPrint::msg, StringJoin[ToString /@ {args}]]` to emulate `Print` (unlike `Print`, this loses formatting, so you can't use it with e.g. `Graphics`!), or `debugPrint[args__] := 
 Message[debugPrint::msg, 
  StringJoin[Riffle[ToString /@ {args}, ", "]]]` to have comma separated arguments.  Preserving formatting is also possible, but it's more advanced so I won't go into it.

Comment: @Anonimous I just realized that `StringForm` is nestable, so you could use the message based `debugPrint` like this too: ```debugPrint[StringForm["x = ``, y = ``", x, y]]``` (or maybe integrate `StringForm`  directly into the function)